How to preload tkinter frames to prevent lag?
I have made a simple tkinter GUI with buttons on the top that switch between different frames. These frames contain various 2D figures that are made using matplotlib. It looks like this:

The 2D data for each figure is size 1000x1000, and there are 25 figures in total. So as you can imagine this takes a long time to load.
I don't mind the GUI taking a long time to load initially as I wouldn't expect matplotlib to be fast, but I do not want lag when switching frames.
Here is what my code looks like. I have tried to cut out as much unnecessary stuff as possible, sorry it's a bit long.
# insert libraries here
#
#
#

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.menu_list = ['Velocity','Momentum flux','Pressure','Force','Compare analytic','Compare custom']
        self.read_data()
        self.menu()
        self.make_frames()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.mainloop()

    def read_data(self):
        # insert code to read data from hdf5 file here
        #
        #
        #

    def menu(self):
        # Make a frame for the menu
        self.menu_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        # Make a button for each option and link the command
        for i, name in enumerate(self.menu_list):
            tk.Button(self.menu_frame, text = name, command = lambda name = name: self.button_pressed(name)).grid(row = 0, column = i)
        # Put menu at the top of the screen
        self.menu_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nw')

    def button_pressed(self, name):
        # Switch frame
        for n in self.menu_list:
            if n == name:
                self.frame_dict[n].grid()
            else:
                self.frame_dict[n].grid_forget()

    def make_frames(self):
        # Initialise a dictionary to hold all the graph frames
        self.frame_dict = {}
        # Initialise the frames
        for name in self.menu_list:
            self.frame_dict[name] = tk.Frame(self)
        # Plot figures in the frames
        # insert various functions here for each frame, for example: 
        self.plot_figs_in_frame( [['u','v'],['du','dv']], self.frame_dict[self.menu_list[0]])
        #
        #
        #

        # Put each graph frame below the menu frame
        for name in self.menu_list:
            self.frame_dict[name].grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        # Choose a frame to start on
        self.button_pressed(self.menu_list[0])

    def plot_figs_in_frame(self, varlist, frame):

        rows = len(varlist)
        columns = len(varlist[0])

        for i, row in enumerate(varlist):
            for j, var in enumerate(row):
                fig = self.make_fig(var)
                canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame)   
                canvas.draw() 
                canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = i, column = j, sticky='nesw')
                plt.close(fig) 

    def make_fig(self, other_inputs):
        # insert matplotlib stuff here
        #
        #
        #
        return fig 

    def on_closing(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.quit()


App()

I thought I could get around this by making all the figures and placing them in the frames before the mainloop. That way I just need to do frame.grid() and frame.grid_forget() when switching between frames. But there is significant lag whenever I press a button for the first time (much less lag after it has been pressed once already).
Is there a way to preload frames, to reduce this lag when pressing buttons?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you could use print() and time to check which element takes time. maybe it is not problem with frames but with loaded data, or with plots - maybe you should first generate plots as images and later use only images.

@furas it's hard to tell exactly what the code is doing using print. It gets through button_pressed() and performs grid() and grid_forget() pretty quickly, but takes a few more seconds to actually display the figures in the GUI. Might try the image idea next, thanks!

As suggested by @furas I have tried saving the figures as images and loading the images into tkinter rather than the matplotlib figures. This massively improved the lag.
here is what I changed
def plot_figs_in_frame(self, varlist, frame, size = 400):

    rows = len(varlist)
    columns = len(varlist[0])

    for i, row in enumerate(varlist):
        for j, var in enumerate(row):
            fig = self.make_fig(var, self.var_dict[var],size)
            fig.savefig('./figures/{}.png'.format(var),dpi = 300)
            plt.close(fig)
           
            image = Image.open('./figures/{}.png'.format(var))
            image.thumbnail((size, size)) 
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            label = ttk.Label(frame, image = photo)
            label.image = photo
            label.grid(row = i, column = j, sticky='nesw')

